# Programmatically bind enum type to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have the following enum.

```
public enum DATABASE_TYPES
        {
            JDataStore, Access, SQLServer, H2, PostGresSQL, MySQL
        };
```

I would like to bind it to a WPF combo box.

I have tried:

```
cmb.ItemsSource = DATABASE_TYPES;
```

but get the error:

```
'ConfigGui.MainWindow.DATABASE_TYPES' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind it to the values of the enum:

```
cmb.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DATABASE_TYPES)).Cast<DATABASE_TYPES>();
```